# R - Performing a CountIF for a multiple rows data frame

Tags: r, countif

I've googled lots of examples about how to perform a CountIF in R, however I still didn't find the solution for what I want.

I basically have 2 dataframes:

```
df1: customer_id | date_of_export - here, we have only 1 date of export per customer
df2: customer_id | date_of_delivery - here, a customer can have different delivery dates (which means, same customer will appear more than once in the list)
```

And I need to count, for each customer_id in df1, how many deliveries they got after the export date. So, I need to `count if df1$customer_id = df2$customer_id AND df1$date_of_export <= df2$date_of_delivery`

To understand better:

```
customer_id | date_of_export
1 | 2018-01-12
2 | 2018-01-12
3 | 2018-01-12

customer_id | date_of_delivery
1 | 2018-01-10
1 | 2018-01-17
2 | 2018-01-13
2 | 2018-01-20
3 | 2018-01-04
```

My output should be:

```
customer_id | date_of_export | deliveries_after_export
1 | 2018-01-12 | 1 (one delivery after the export date)    
2 | 2018-01-12 | 2 (two deliveries after the export date)
3 | 2018-01-12 | 0 (no delivery after the export date)
```

Doesn't seem that complicated but I didn't find a good approach to do that. I've been struggling for 2 days and nothing accomplished.

I hope I made myself clear here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest merging the two `data.frames` together and then it's a simple `sum()`:

```
library(data.table)
df3 <- merge(df1, df2)
setDT(df3)[, .(deliveries_after_export = sum(date_of_delivery > date_of_export)), by = .(customer_id, date_of_export)]

#   customer_id date_of_export deliveries_after_export
#1:           1     2018-01-12                       1
#2:           2     2018-01-12                       2
#3:           3     2018-01-12                       0
```

Comment: Thanks. This sound very clever. However, this is still bringing the date_of_delivery in the dataframe so I'm having more than 1 row per customer (one row for each delivery date).

Is there a way to get rid off this column and bring the sum of deliveries per customer?

Comment: Nevermind, my bad. It's indeed working! I knew it wasn't that complicated but I didn't know you would solve it in few seconds. VERY APPRECIATED!!

Comment: Hi buddy, hope you will be able to see this.

I have a question. I tried to include another column which the price paid for each delivery. And the result I want is the same: sum of total price paid, per customer.

As far as I've understood, here we are simply counting as 1 when the date_of_delivery > date_of_export, which makes sense, when each date has only 1 delivery. However, how do I sum the price of delivery? A delivery can cost $40 while another one can cost $50, and in this case, I would like to have $90 as result in another column right next to deliveries_after_export. Any idea?

Comment: @Kreiven Maybe: `setDT(df3)[, .(deliveries_after_export = sum(date_of_delivery > date_of_export), price_after_export = sum(price[date_of_delivery > date_of_export])), by = .(customer_id, date_of_export)]`?

Comment: PERFECT. I tried something like that but I wasn't sure where to select "price" as object. So, that would be actually a SUMIFS instead of COUNTIFS, but works the same way. Glad to learn this, it will help me so much in the future. ;) Thanks again, pal.